# layout design in android

Tags: android, android-layout

i have used the following xml code to create the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/main_layout"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone" />
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

     <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zero"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/six"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/seven"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/eight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/eight"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nine"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finish"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/finish"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/table"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/OK"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:visibility="visible" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

as i am a new user it is not letting me to post the output image. the last two buttons Ok and home are coming immediately after the table. I want them to be moved down towards the screen ( large and centered as well). i want the textbox to appear after leaving some space from the top of the screen. how to add empty spaces to make it look better and what properties should i refer , please suggest me..

Comment: Dear please post possible scratch (wireframe design) of your layout. it will help us to understand clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have some space between the widgets you could use the [`margin`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) attribute. Example, if you want the `EditText` to have some space at the top you could use `android:layout_marginTop="5dp"`. To set the last `LinearLayout` at the bottom add `android:alignParentBottom="true"` and to center the buttons add to the same `LinearLayout` this, `android:gravity="center`.

Comment: thanks slukian, one more glitch i have. how to add the space between the Ok and Home button,which are in same linear layout.i want them to look somewhat bigger and at left and right ends,i have tried the gravity attribute,but somehow it  is not working.

Comment: use padding for spacing between buttons

Comment: @KumarRaja bigger in what sense, height, width, distance between the text and the borders? Do you want the buttons to occupy the entire layout? If you have an image with the layout as you want it please upload it somewhere and then edit your message with the link so i can see it.

Answer (score 0):

To make **OK** and **Home** buttons left and right change the Layout of these 2 buttons from **Linear to Relative**.

Use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` in OK button and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` in Home button. remove all gravity attributes in these 2 buttons.

I hope it may help you.